# Editing CSS by using external configuration file or override it using HTML

Tags: html, css

I currently developing interface for a system using Microsoft visual studio, and I want to create a configuration file that could change the properties of my `CSS` content without editing back `CSS` using Microsoft visual studio for example changing container color, font size and type of font just by choosing and click at the configuration file/page .

```
.Container2{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    font-size: 4vmax;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
}
```

but the configuration only limited like only could change color and text align.

My friend said I could use HTML and it will override my `CSS` but will not change the `CSS` default, just override it only.

I have no idea about this and how to do this, so anyone could help tell me what should I do and what should I use, I will start do google once I know the method that I should use. Any information or suggestion for me is needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several css files with different styles and you can programmatically change the css file path to your preference. That way, you can have multiple themes for your website too.

Comment: how can i do like this 
Font Color:
[ ] Red
[ ] Blue
[ ] Green
[ ] Black
[/] White

so i could change the properties of my css just by clicking at the box to change it.